# MySQL won't start in XAMPP, Starting by terminal makes phpmyadmin page blank

Tags: database, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP a week ago. It was working good 1st week but in second week, the database not started by manager-osx.

So I have started the server by terminal,

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

And the server was started, I thought problem was solved.
But when I open http://localhost/phpmyadmin The page is blank

I have also tried:

`sudo killall mysqld`
This shows no mysqld process is running.

Also tried this.

```
sudo su
ps aux | grep mysql
kill -9 {process id}
```

But it doesnot work for me.

How can I solve this issue, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly same problem, & tried various of solutions finally:

1 go to you xamppfile>phpmyadmin.

2 make a copy of config.inc.php in another place (just in case)

3 delete the config.inc.php and now phpmyadmin is working again!

4 make a copy of config.sample.inc.php and rename it to config.inc.php

5 open it and change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

hope it work for you.